# Google Maps v2 without Play Services

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, google-play-services

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Google Maps V2 as fragment,
but with a fallback showing the map in a WebView if user don't have Google Play Services installed?

This is because Chinese users often don't have this installed.

Comment: That should work, assuming that you can get what you want from "showing the map in a WebView". What specifically is your concern?

Comment: The problem is during install, I get: Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY when Google Play Services is not installed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is during install, I get: Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY when Google Play Services is not installed. Any thoughts?

Since Maps V2 does not require a `<uses-library>` element, remove yours from your manifest. You probably have that left over from Maps V1, which did require a `<uses-library>` element.

If you are simultaneously trying to support Maps V1, Maps V2, and another alternative, add `android:required="false"` to the `<uses-library>` element for Maps V1. Then, you will need to detect at runtime if you have that library (e.g., call `Class.forName()` for `com.google.android.maps.MapActivity` and see if it succeeds).